# Incrementing a variable by a real number (not integer)

Tags: bash

I wanted to increment a variable, `k` inside a loop. Each increment is by 0.025.
I tried using:

`let "k += 0.025"`

and

`let "$k += 0.025"`

and

`k += 0.025`

and many other variations. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174841/incrementing-a-variable-by-0-025-for-each-loop-in-bash-not-loop-variable).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how many users are on superuser, and I've had good experience with response-time on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point. Ksh93 and zsh do.

In Bash, you can use `bc` or `awk`:

```
k=$(echo "$k + 0.025" | bc -l)
```

or

```
k=$(awk -v "k=$k" 'BEGIN { print k + 0.025 }')
```

In some cases it might be more convenient to write whole scripts or sections in AWK rather than try to pass values in and out and do awkward comparisons.

Comment: I tried using the bc command you gave me and I get `line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `k=$(echo "$k + 0.025" | bc -l)'
`

Comment: @Amit: It works fine for me. Note that `k` would need to be initialized. If it's unset, `bc` will issue an error. The error you received is from the shell, however. Are you using Bash? What version?